# Kendo UI export to pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, kendo-ui, export

Sorry for my English at first :-) 
I have a web site! And only one page I need to export to PDF. 
I use `kendo.all.min.js` and it works excellent on desktop browsers!
I read documentation and found that mobile browsers not support (((
But i need export only one page .... Would you so kind help me with this problem! Only this part of code i need to work on mobile devices

My JS: (button.js)

```
var generatePDF = function() {
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#formConfirmation")).then(function(group) {
    kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf");
});
}

kendo.pdf.defineFont({
"DejaVu Sans"             : "/lk-tst/fonts/Sans.ttf",
});
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{title}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1, minimum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site_001.css">
<script src="/lk-tst/pdfmake/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lk-tst/pdfmake/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lk-tst/pdfmake/button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="formConfirmation">
            <button onclick="generatePDF().open();">Save as PDF</button>
            {pers_plan}
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
        {copyright}
    </div>
</div>
{script}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can call the saveAsExcel(); function to save your page to an excel file.

Comment: I know, but same problem, it’s not working via mobile browser